# Does the word Approver exist?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to use this word in the context of approve / reject workflows, for example vacation or other stuff.

Does it exist ?

Comment: google google google...

Comment: This is what a dictionary is for. You can find them online. They'll answer your question a lot faster than this site!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, Approver is in common use with the meaning you intend.  I am an ancient Systems Analyst and I know these things.